# Print on Terminal while using SDL C

Tags: c, terminal, sdl

I'm writing a program in SDL with the only problem that I want the user to put some input from the terminal, but when I do printf nothing appears.
I found this [thread](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=4887.0)

Here they say:

```
I believe SDL redirects all output intended for stdout/stderr to files stdout.txt/stderr.txt. Check the folder your program runs in for those files.
```

but nothing is in he folder from where i launch the program.
Anyone know how to find this file(if they are useful for what I need to do, or a way to print an output in the terminal with C using the SDL library?

here is the code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//line algorithm http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/246895-draw-lines-in-c-with-sdl/


char *inputString(FILE* fp, size_t size){
//The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional
    char *str;
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
    if(!str)return str;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n'){
        str[len++]=ch;
        if(len==size){
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size+=16));
            if(!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++]='\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char *imagePath;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Input Image Path(just image if in exectuable folder):\n");
        imagePath = inputString(stdin, 10);
        printf("%s\n", imagePath);
    }
    printf("ciao\n");
    free(imagePath);
    static const int winWidth = 640;
    static const int winHeight = 480;
    int go;
    SDL_Event event;

    //creating the window
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *canvas = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Drawing Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, winWidth, winHeight, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    canvas = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    SDL_FillRect(canvas, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(canvas->format, 255, 255, 170));

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    go = 0;
    while( go==0 )
    {


        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch( event.type )
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            go = 1;
            break;

        }

        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SDL2 no longer does that and shouldn't interfere with our output at all. If you're on windows things are complicated, as it have multiple meanings on where output shoud go for different program types. Make a 'console' program (`-mconsole` for mingw, `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` for msvc linker, ...).

Comment: Mmh, I don't really know what's that stuff...And google doesn't tell much to me...Do you have any advice where I could take a look?

Comment: If you use some IDE there usually is 'console application' project type (I'm generally against IDEs, but it might be a good place to start).

Comment: No I'm not using any IDE< I'm using the Linux Terminal to compile

Comment: Huh, I'm completely misled. Then show the minimal code, it may be e.g. your printf string don't have `\n` and hence isn't flushed.

Comment: I added my code in the description

Comment: Don't do `freopen` unless you absolutely have to (not in this case - "CON" is dos/windows specific), and as I've said your printf don't have newline; either add it or manually flush it with `fflush`.

Comment: Can't believe i struggled 5 hours and 30 just to realise it was a "\n" Thanks!

Comment: But this was a basic code, now when I try to add that "\n" to my real code, it doesn't work.(I edited in the question)

Comment: Works for me, except this infinite loop at the beginning of `main` that never breaks. You don't see any output at all?

Comment: I don't know why. I just copied the same exact code into a new file, and it works. But if I try to compile the file from which I just did the code(the one I copied in my question), then it doesn't work, for no reason...